# mongoose - divide and round

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hey my question is very simple but I can't figure it out:
I have a huge mongoose collection `player` with a field `money`. How can I divide this value by 100 and have a round number (no decimal)

I tried

```
players.update({}, {$mul: {'money':.01}}, {multi: true}).exec()
```

It works for dividing by 100 but I don't know how to round it?

By the way, why isn't there any documentation about the `$mul` operator on the official mongoose documentation ?
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/3.0.x/docs/api.html

Thanks folks

Comment: `$mul` is a MongoDB operator and have nothing to do with Mongoose. You'll find its documentation [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/mul/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently MongoDb doesn't have any in-built operators to support `Math.ceil()` or `Math.floor()` functions. You need to do it on the application server or write a  javascript function which resides on the database server and does the same.

### Implementing it in the application code:

```
Players.find().forEach(function(doc){
var updated = Math.ceil(doc.money/100);
Players.update({"_id":doc._id},{$set:{"money":updated}});
})
```

### Implementing it as server side Javascript function:

```
db.system.js.insert({"_id":"updateMoney","value":function(num){
    db.players.find().forEach(function(doc){
    var updated = Math.ceil(doc.money/num);
    db.players.update({"_id":doc._id},{$set:{"money":updated}});
})
}})
```

and invoking the function from mongoose:

```
mongoose.connection.on("open", function(err){
  mongoose.connection.db.eval("updateMoney(100)", function (err, retval) {
      console.log('err: '+err);
      console.log('retval: '+retval);
  });
});
```

[$mul](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/mul/) is a mongoDB operator, mongoose is an API which enables us to use these operators to query mongodb.

Comment: Thanks. It answers my question. I wanted to update the whole collection at once but it doesn't seem possible. Do you know if we can define its own operators?

Comment: Please see my updated answer to update it in a single operation. The script needs to exist on the database server and be invoked from mongoose API. If we were to implement our own operator we need to do it in the mongodb c++ source code and build it.

Answer (score 0):

For Mongoose 4 and 4+ versions you have getters and setters. So goto to player schema and
Add `set: v => Math.round(v)` to you **money** field.
Like

```
money: {
  type: Number,
  set: v => Math.round(v)
  ...
}
```